# Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting angular ng-repeat infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite

Template code

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="itemList in itemLists" href="#/app/itemDetail/{{itemList.itemnum}}">
      <h2 class="title">  {{itemList.itemnum}} </h2>
        <h4 class="title">  {{itemList.itemdes}} </h4>
          <h4 class="title">  {{itemList.binnum}} </h4>
  </ion-item>
```

Controller code

```
dataFactory.getItemDetails(categoryID).then(function (data_) {        
    $scope.itemLists =  data_.rows;
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('Error getting the data' + error);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });**strong text**
```

First time I am posting question here.I am not able to identify what's wrong here ng-repeate is going in an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you post your ng-repeat attribute expression too.

Comment: Thanks Ste2425. There is no attribute expression  for ng-repete.